# Powershell search in a hashtable with multiple values ​and then change it

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable in which there are 2 keys "hostname" and "description", each with 2 values ​​"Server1" "Server2" is assigned to hostname. "Windows2022" and "Windows2016" is assigned to the key "Description".

I would now like to change the description for Server2. How do I do this in a multiple values

Does anyone here have an idea

Here is my Hashtable as an example

```
$Hashtable = @{
    'Hostname' = @('Server1','Server2')
    'Description' = @('Windows2022', 'Windows2023')
}
Write-Host($Hashtable.Keys + $Hashtable.Values)
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to retain this data structure (two aligned lists, rather than a single list of objects with 2 properties each)?

Comment: I recommend to use **Write-Output** rather than **Write-Host** - more info can be found [Difference between Write-Output and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/02/write-output-vs-write-host-in-powershell.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty inefficient storage design - you'll have to search through the whole `hostname` array to find the hostname, then update the corresponding entry in the `description` array by index:

```
$hostIndex = $Hashtable['hostname'].IndexOf('Server02')
if ($hostIndex -ge 0) {
    $Hashtable['description'][$hostIndex] = 'New description'
}
```

---

I'd strongly suggest organizing your hashtable with the hostname as the key, and another hashtable or a custom object as the value - this way you'll have all the information about a specific hostname tied together:

```
@(
  @{ Hostname = 'Server1'; Description = 'Windows2022' }
  @{ Hostname = 'Server2'; Description = 'Windows2023' }
) |ForEach-Object -Begin { $Hashtable = @{} } -Process {
  $Hashtable[$_.Hostname] = [pscustomobject]$_
}
```

Now changing the description for `Server2` becomes much simpler:

```
$Hashtable['Server2'].Description = 'New description goes here'
```